# qml filedialog path in android

Tags: android, qml

i have android link problem
when i call filedialoge the path gives me : " Accepted:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ff"
instead of / gives me% 2 or% 2A
FileDialog {
    id:configFile
        //selectExisting: false
        modality: Qt.WindowModal
        nameFilters: ["Text files (*.s)"]
        onAccepted: {
           
          console.log("Accepted: " + configFile.fileUrl)
           MainWindow.loadconfigfile(configFile.fileUrl)

           }

       onRejected: { console.log("Rejected")   }
}
```

for qt5 information

Basé sur Qt 5.13.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)

Built on Oct 4 2019 04:22:26

for android
android_arm64_v8a

I tested the following example https://github.com/kullo/qml-file-dialog-demo but it gives me the same problem

Comment: It is unclear what your problem would be. Starting with which filedialog you would use. Please format your post to make it readable.

Comment: From the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#fileUrl-prop): _Note: This property is set only if exactly one file was selected. In all other cases, it will be empty._. You probably select more the one file. Check the [fileUrls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#fileUrls-prop) property to be sure.

Comment: the problem is  output of fileUrls : Accepted: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ffile.s   why %3A and 2%F or not / /

Comment: FileDialog {
        id:configFile
            //selectExisting: false
            modality: Qt.WindowModal
            nameFilters: ["Text files (*.s)"]
            onAccepted: {
                var path = configFile.fileUrl

               console.log("Accepted: " +  path)
               MainWindow.loadconfigfile(path)

               }

           onRejected: { console.log("Rejected")   }
    }

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue and solution can be: **decodeURIComponent**(configFile.fileUrl).